# Implementing GCM In android

Tags: android

I implement the android hive demo of GCM in my application but when we register the device on server it is successfully registered , but when we send the message . it will not come on device . I am in trouble .

Please help me 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you created a `browser key` or `server key`? There is a issue with your key.

Comment: i create the server key sir

Comment: Have you set that key to your back end side? Also is your registration key is store back end database? What error did you get in browser when you send a message?

Comment: i am not getting any error but when we send the message from server to device, it is not send. and not showing any kind of error.

Comment: Have you checked at your side?? Have you checked the variable name which they have passed to your side?

Comment: yes i have checked it multiple time . all things are fine.

Comment: In your manifest file have you added all permission?

Comment: i give all the permission

Comment: I need to check your manifest file. Please post it. Also sure that `SENDER_ID` should be correct.

Comment: how i send the manifest file

Comment: You need to post here

Comment: have u got team viewer if yes than i will send u my tem viewer id and pass

Comment: No. I haven't but yes you can mail me. Get my id from my SO profile

Comment: i am sending the manifest file to your mail id please check and revert me if any thing wrong in my manifest .

Comment: have u seen the manifest file

Comment: Yes. All is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have a checklist here, it is a bit tricky to understand the cause:

- Under APIs & auth > APIs
  Enable - Google Cloud Messaging for Android
- Under APIs & auth > Credentials:
  Click Add a new key, select add a new server key and add the server IP to allowed IPs list (or 0.0.0.0/0)
- On Overview page check the **project number**, check if this corresponds with the registration ID you are using on gcm.register("project number here") on the android app.

Comment: What about the server IP?

Comment: 10.25.97.254 ip addresss